# Can't insert into sqlite3 database in cocos2dx

Tags: sqlite, cocos2d-x

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open(dtPath.c_str(), &database) == SQLITE_OK &&
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, String::createWithFormat("select * from data where level = %i", level + 1)->getCString(), -1, &stmt, nullptr) == SQLITE_OK &&
    sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // do somthing..
}

int statusCode  = (sqlite3_exec(database, "insert into data values(20, 'abc')", NULL, NULL, NULL));
CCLOG("%i", statusCode);
```

when i run, the statusCode = 5 (SQLITE_BUSY), i dont know why ?? Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use `sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt)` in the if body? [doc](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html)